# Dagger2 mvvm android Module must be set

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a beginner level question regarding dagger in android. Kindly see the snippet for a quick grasp.
The goal is to provide CentralRepo instance in my view model class via Dependency Injection.

Say, I have the following classes with dependency as below,

```
MyViewModel -> ctor( //initing.. mCentralRepo = CentralRepo.getInstance(RemoteRepo.getInstance) );

CentralRepo -> cror (@para RemoteRepo)
```

Now, these are my module classes

1. MyRemoteRepositoyModule

   ```
   @Module  
   public class MyRemoteRepositoryModule {  

    /**
     * Method to provide an instance of {@link RemoteRepository}
     *
     * @return RemoteRepository.
     */
    @Singleton 
    @Provides
    RemoteRepository provideRemoteRepository() {
        return RemoteRepository.getInstance();
    }
   }
   ```
2. MyCentralRepositoryModule

   ```
    @Module  
    public class MyCentralRepositoryModule {  
    private RemoteRepository mRemoteRepository;

    public MyCentralRepositoryModule(RemoteRepository remoteRepository) {
        mRemoteRepository = remoteRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Method to provide an instance of {@link CentralRepository}
     *
     * @return MyCentralRepository.
     */
    @Singleton 
    @Provides
    MyCentralRepository provideMyCentralRepository() {
        return MyCentralRepository.getInstance(mRemoteRepository);
    }
   }
   ```
3. and lastly, Component class (IMyComponent)

   ```
     @Singleton
      @Component(modules = {MyRemoteRepositoryModule.class,  
      MyCentralRepositoryModule.class})  
      public interface IMyComponent {


      /**
      * Targeting injection in VM.
      */
      public void injectInViewModel(MyAndroidViewModel viewModel);
   }
   ```

and Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    
    private IMyComponent mComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
      
        // doubtful?
        mComponent = DaggerIMyComponent.builder().myRemoteRepositoryModule(new MyRemoteRepositoryModule()).build();
            
       //
    }
   }
```

Now, If I try to inject this in my view model class
I got an error

> MyCentralRepositoryModule must be set

I am sure I have missed something, It'd be appreciated If you could point out the mistake.

Comment: That's a lot of code you don't need. You're trying to manually resolve the graph with manually creating the "graph" in your modules, instead of just adding `@Singleton public class MyCentralRepository { @Inject(RemoteRepository remoteRepository) {}` and not adding a module.

Answer (score 1):

your `IMyComponent` defines that you will only gonna inject those modules in `MyAndroidViewModel`, and you are building your component in Application context. now it has two possibilities.

1 - Either change the parameter of your component method from `MyAndroidViewModel` to `Application`

```
  @Singleton
  @Component(modules = {
      MyRemoteRepositoryModule.class, 
      MyCentralRepositoryModule.class
  })  
  public interface IMyComponent {
      public void injectInViewModel(Application application);
  }
```

then use this block

```
DaggerIMyComponent.builder().myCentralRepositoryModule(new MyRemoteRepositoryModule()).build().injectInViewModel(this);
```

2- Or Build the component in `MyAndroidViewModel` by adding below code in class

```
init{
DaggerIMyComponent.builder().myCentralRepositoryModule(new MyRemoteRepositoryModule()).build().injectInViewModel(this);
}
```